# Powershell and Rest API Postmark

Tags: powershell, postmark

when I send a request through powershell to rest api Postmarkapp I have these errors

**When use metod get**

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.
```

**When use  metod post**

```
Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Requested URL: /deliverystats
```

**Script**

```
$Uri         = 'https://api.postmarkapp.com/deliverystats'
Invoke-RestMethod $Uri -Method Post -Headers @{'X-Postmark-Server-Token' =" Token" }  -ContentType "application/json" |
```

Comment: Have you tried to test your requests with `curl` as specified [here](https://postmarkapp.com/developer/api/bounce-api)?

Answer (score 0):

The script you provided wasn't complete - it ends with a `|`. 
A valid token is required before executing a request or you'll get this error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"ErrorCode":10,"Message":"No Account or Server API tokens were supplied in the HTTP headers. Please add a header for either 
X-Postmark-Server-Token or X-Postmark-Account-Token."}
```

Your code had `' Token'`, which is a constant and is probably not a valid value for the `X-Postmark-Server-Token` or `X-Postmark-Account-Token` header. You didn't show how `$Token` was set, but it probably should have been something like this:

```
$Token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' #your account specific token
$uri = 'https://api.postmarkapp.com/deliverystats'
```

Then add the headers like this (with a `$` before `Token`):

```
Invoke-RestMethod $Uri -Method Get -Headers @{'X-Postmark-Server-Token' ="$Token" }  -ContentType "application/json"
```